# iOS Facebook Login "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration"

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch

Believe me, I have read all the other questions on this topic. None of them solved my problem (or were even quite the same problem). Facebook login has been working perfectly fine for me for weeks... Until yesterday when suddenly it started breaking and giving me this error.

Before yesterday, when I logged into my app with the Facebook SDK `logInWithReadPermissions` method, it would say "You've already authorized [app name]!" and be perfectly happy to log me in and move on. Then suddenly it started failing with this error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. To use this URL you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings.

The weird part is I hadn't changed any of the Facebook app's settings at all. This just suddenly started happening; five minutes before it worked, next build it didn't. Nevertheless, I looked up the error message and found a ton of things people suggested to do on the facebook developer page to fix the problem... Mostly involving the `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` field, not that I could quite get a clear answer of what you're supposed to put in there for **an iOS app**... They always said to put your website address. I don't have a website, I have an app... What gives?

So I knew I hadn't made any changes to the Facebook developer area to cause it to break, and I'd tried every change there that I could find on the internet. So I pulled down an old working copy to test that, on the off chance that somehow code I'd written was the problem. Nope; code from a week ago, that worked perfectly fine, still gives me the same message.

If the problem isn't in the code, and changing things on the FB site doesn't do it... I'm out of ideas. If there's something else I need to do on the FB app to fix this, suggest away and I'll give it a try... And if it works that's great, but I'm still not going to understand why it broke in the first place when I didn't make any changes... Anybody able to help me out?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. For me this happens only with app store version. But when I tried the local build(which I am pretty sure that it is same as app store) it just worked fine. This was working for me too a month back. All I can say is that facebook app policy sucks.

Comment: Were you able to sort this out? I can't seem to figure out what is causing this issue and I have checked the details of the app in developers.facebook.com and it has been setup for the iOS platform?

Comment: I know this is old but I am same issue on my iOS .. can you share your solution

Answer (score 42):

I had exactly the same issue.
Actually you just have to add platform in your app settings

So here are the steps

1. Open https://developers.facebook.com and select your app
2. Settings > Basic > Add Platform

   [image]

3.Now select iOS from the window and add your Bundle ID and rest of the information and click on Save changes
[image]

and that's it.
Hope it helps you .. All the best

Comment: Always Happy to help :) @AbhishekThapliyal

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue today.

Same thing Facebook kept saying "You've already authorized [app name]!" in the past. Which I found strange since all my other apps didn't display this message.

In the end I figured that I didn't add an iOS platform for the Facebook app in Settings. I don't understand why it worked before :)

So try to add an iOS platform and don't forget to add your bundle ID.

I hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I remember having a similar problem with a website that used Facebook to apply a discount "friend of the business page? get x% off your order" - anyhoo, turns out I needed to add both the www and non-www versions of the website to the settings in the Facebook App (https://developers.facebook.com -> My App -> Settings -> App Domains)

I've revisited this and added "iOS" as a native platform (found at My App -> Settings) # This would be first thing to check. The second thing would be to look at the "Quick Start" section for further assistance, which can be found in the top-right section of that iOS app settings.

Facebook can and will change things willy-nilly so it's unpredictable as to when things break or not.

I'd be interested to know when/if and how you resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I added this is code in AndroidMainfest.xml and then it's work!

```
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: For iOS:

Open the ios/Runner/Info.plist file.
Locate the <dict> tag.
Inside the <dict> tag, add the following lines:
xml
Copy code
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<string>YES</string>

Comment: @"Layla Shams Aldeen" if this solves de problem should be posted as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: If the answer is so simple, should be posted as answer to be recognized.