# Logging in through Facebook not working for my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

My app has a setup where users can log in normally through Email and Password entry or through their Facebook login credentials.

For handling log in through Facebook, I am using Facebook dependencies through Cocoapods. Also I had recently updated these dependencies.

Podfile Snippet:-

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

My Podfile.lock Snippet:-

```
- FacebookCore (0.5.0):
    - Bolts (~> 1.9)
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.37)
- FacebookLogin (0.5.0):
    - Bolts (~> 1.9)
    - FacebookCore (~> 0.5)
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.37)
    - FBSDKLoginKit (~> 4.37)
- FacebookShare (0.5.0):
    - Bolts (~> 1.9)
    - FacebookCore (~> 0.5)
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.37)
    - FBSDKShareKit (~> 4.37)
- FBSDKCoreKit (4.38.1):
    - Bolts (~> 1.9)
- FBSDKLoginKit (4.38.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit
- FBSDKShareKit (4.38.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit
```

Users can log in using their Facebook credentials on through the Facebook  website through Safari browser using the email/phone number password credentials

The problem comes when users try to log in through the Facebook App in their iPhones.

These are the screenshots of the problem at hand.

The first Screenshot shows the facebook login page through my app:-

[image: the login screen]

The next Screenshot shows the error when trying to log in through the facebook app:-

[image: The error screen]

While searching for a solution, I came across this post:-
[Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428357/facebook-login-callback-not-working-when-using-facebook-app-swift)

And based on this post, I checked my info.plist. it seems valid

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb{facebook-app-id}</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
...
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{facebook-app-id}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{facebook-display-name}</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

This is the code I have for Facebook-related Login in the login view controller:-

```
func facebookLoginButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()

    loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [ReadPermission.publicProfile, ReadPermission.email], viewController : self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            if let token = accessToken.authenticationToken ?? nil{
                let params = ["access_token": token as AnyObject, "account_type":  PineSimpleData.getOnboardingAccountType()! as AnyObject]
                let url = "/user/connect/facebook"
                self.socialLogin(params: params, url: url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code Snippets in the AppDelegate:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ....
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    var handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    if handled {
        return true
    }
    ....
    return handled
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) {
        return true
    }
    ....
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

Logging in through both the app and the Facebook website was working fine until now. How should I handle this error? Has something been made mandatory in the facebook developers section? If so, what am I supposed to change in the facebook developer page? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you register your app in the facebook dev portal?

Comment: I think so. Don't know much, but Facebook login would not have been possible if the app was not registered. I even have the facebook app id in my info.plist

Answer (score 1):

below are the basics steps:-

```
  1.Open https://developers.facebook.com and select your app

   2.Settings > Basic > Add Platform

   3.Now select iOS from the window and add your Bundle ID and rest of the information and click on Save changes.
```

same problem you can check it here:- [iOS Facebook Login "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883079/ios-facebook-login-given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook application query is only `fb`.
You need to update your plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

Comment: The result is the same. The error still occurs. Is it only the plist alone that I have to update?

Comment: Well that might be one of the cases, but also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883079/ios-facebook-login-given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration

Answer (score 0):

There is a toggle in facebook developer dashboard which determines whether the app is native or not.
May be you forgot to turn if on.
[Check this image for exact location of that setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me2rc.png)